# Different behaviours between generic and direct type remapping in typescript

Tags: typescript

I tried to remap an array to to into another and found that would be different `direct remap` and `generic remap`.

The `generic remap` works as expected while the `direct remap` remains some properties from Array class which is not expected.

```js
type Input = [string, number, boolean]


// Generic remap as expected
type Remap<T> = { [I in keyof T]: T[I] }
type Output1 = Remap<Input>
//   type Output1 = [string, number, boolean].

// Direct remap but unexpected
type Output2 = { [I in keyof Input]: Input[I] }
/*   type Output2 = {
    [x: number]: string | number | boolean;
    0: string;
    1: number;
    2: boolean;
    length: 3;
    toString: () => string;
    toLocaleString: () => string;
    pop: () => string | number | boolean | undefined;
    push: (...items: (string | ... 1 more ... | boolean)[]) => number;
    ... 26 more ...;
    readonly [Symbol.unscopables]: {
        ...;
    };
} */
```

Is that possible to direct remap without Array class properties?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: No, as per [ms/TS#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995). Right now the only way to get a mapped array to be an array is with indirection. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes. Nice to have a detailed explaination.

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance. It might not be right away because I need to go to sleep soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, the support to [map array/tuple types to array/tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) only works when that type is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter. This is considered a bug in TypeScript, as reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995). Although it's been around for such a long time that I'm not sure if it will ever be fixed.  There was some work done in [microsoft/TypeScript#48443](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48433) to address it, but that pull request seems to just be languishing in limbo (as of TypeScript 5.3).  For now, then, you'll need to work around this issue by refactoring your direct version

```
type Mapped = {[K in keyof ArrType]: ⋯K⋯}
```

to an indirect version, either by using a new generic type alias:

```
type Mapper<T> = {[K in keyof T]: ⋯K⋯}
type Mapped = Mapper<ArrType>
```

or by using [conditional type `infer`erence](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to declare a new generic type parameter:

```
type Mapped = ArrType extends infer T ? {[K in keyof T]: ⋯K⋯} : never
```

Comment: The `infer` version seems to be simpler.